# Fix Partition Table

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, partition-recovery

I am trying to partially restore a previous system image with a slightly different partition table and Windows 10 keeps trying (and failing) automatic repair.

I need help fixing the partition table.

---

### Setup Background

---

I will denote the "current" (i.e. layout before restoring backup images) as layout **A**. Layout **A** partition table is as follow (sector size: 512):

```
DEVICE     START          END     SECTORS     SIZE     TYPE
A-P1        2048      1023999     1021952     499M     Windows Recovery Environment
A-P2     1024000      1228799      204800     100M     EFI System
A-P3     1228800      1261567       32768      16M     Microsoft Reserved
A-P4     1261568    625827839   624566271     298G     Microsoft Basic Data
A-P5   625827840   2000406527  1374578688   655.5G     Microsoft Basic Data
```

Note that `A-P4` and `A-P5` are encrypted with Bitlocker in layout **A**.

I will denote the backup images I am attempting to restore as layout **B**. The original system from which backup **B** was created had a smaller, `B-P4` and consequently, larger `B-P5` relative to layout **A**. However, `B-P5` is a full of user data (no OS data) and therefore `B-P5` was not backup and and the current `A-P5` will be preserved. Below are the images I have available to restore:

```
 FILE                      SIZE
 B-bs=512_count=2048.dd    1,048,576
 B-P1.dd                   523,239,424     (same size as A-P1)
 B-P2.dd                   104,857,600     (same size as A-P2)
 B-P3.dd                   16,777,216      (same size as A-P3)
 B-P4.dd                   267,349,131,264 (SMALLER than A-P4)
```

Since I do not want to change the boundary of `A-P5` since I want to preserve its (bitlocker encrypted) data, I did not restore the first 2048 sectors of the disk. Instead I used GParted to change the `B-P4` end boundary to reflect the `B-P4.dd` file size. Accordingly, the partition table looks as follows:

```
DEVICE     START          END     SECTORS     SIZE     TYPE
B-P1        2048      1023999     1021952     499M     Windows Recovery Environment
B-P2     1024000      1228799      204800     100M     EFI System
B-P3     1228800      1261567       32768      16M     Microsoft Reserved
B-P4     1261568    523427839   522166272     249G     Microsoft Basic Data
A/B-P5 625827840   2000406527  1374578688   655.5G     Microsoft Basic Data
```

I then restored `B-P1`, `B-P2`, `B-P3`, and `B-P4`, with files, `B-P1.dd`, `B-P2.dd`, `B-P3.dd`, and `B-P4.dd`, respectively. Also, note that the restored `B-P4`/`B-P4.dd` is not encrypted.

Once restored, I was able to mount, `mount B-P4 /mnt`, the unencrypted Windows OS partition with success.

---

### What I Tried

---

I tried to fix the partition table in Windows Advanced Repair Command Prompt as follows:

1. bootrec /fixmbr (success)
2. bootrec /fixboot (fail / "access denied")
3. DISKPART: assign letter to EFI partition (letter N:)
4. Format N: to FAT32
5. bcdboot d:\windows /s n: /f uefi (failed / not in windows store)

I stopped here before doing real damage. I reimaged the EFI partition `B-P2`.

---

### Other "useful" Information

---

The **B** backup layout I am restoring is Windows 10 1804. The **A** layout was for Windows 10 20H1. I am in the process of creating a USB recovery drive from another Windows 10 20H1 computer that I will have at my disposal.

If not already apparent, I have access to Ubuntu Live and the images were created/restored using Ubuntu.

---

### Parting Thoughts

---

How can I fix the partition table so that `B-P4` (unencrypted) boots to Windows while preserving the boundaries of the (bitlocker encrypted) `A-P5` partition?

Answer (score 0):

So, I rolled the dice with the following and it seems to have worked.

1. Restored first 2048 sectors with backup image, `B-bs=512_count=2048.dd`
2. Restored `P1 - P4` with respective backup images
3. In `fdisk`, deleted `A-P5` partition (since it wasn't correctly aligned after restoring first 2048 sectors of backup image)
4. In `fdisk`, created new `P5` with correct boundaries for `A-P5`

After that, I rebooted and Windows loaded normally. I was also able to mount the bitlocker encrypted `A-P5` partition and it appears to have been unaffected.

I should not that I also had a backup of the **A** disk in case I needed to start over. I would always recommend a complete backup before screwing around with restoring old images. Having that backup is the only reason I risked deleting and re-created `A-P5` boundaries (as I personally lack expertise level knowledge on how MBR/UEFI partition tables work).